# How to subtract the dates in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to subtract the dates, but it only subtract the month. I am passing the params[:date] from view to controller in the mm/dd/yyyy format.
i have a code in controller

```
include AgeCalculatorHelper
def new
  @age = AgeCalculator.date_subtr(params[:date])
  render :index
end
```

In helpers.rb

```
require 'date'
class AgeCalculator
  def self.date_subtr(date)
    (Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%y').to_i - date.to_i)
  end
```

I tried without `to_i` it through the error 
`undefined method`-'`for "08/21/16":String Did you mean? -@`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are parsing the wrong variable. Try this

```
def self.date_subtr(date)
  Date.today - Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
end
```

This parses a date in the format of "mm/dd/yyy" and subtracts it from the current date. I think this will give you the number of days in between the two dates.

Edit:

You can output years months and days like this

```
days = Date.today - Date.strptime('08-09-1991', '%m-%d-%Y')
"#{days.to_i / 365} years #{days.to_i % 12} months #{days.to_i % 365} days"
```

Comment: yeah,  it returns the days. :)

Comment: Does this do what you are trying to do?

Comment: Divide the days by 365 to get the years. Divide the days by 12 to get the months.

Comment: Okay. that's fine, i want like this, for example user enter his dob like `08-09-1991` , he want calculate his age till date. What i am trying is result will be `24 years 11 months 13 days`

Comment: @Mani
I think you are looking for something like this - https://github.com/tmlee/time_difference#you-can-also-get-in_general-as-a-human-readable-string-using-humanize

Comment: @Mani If this answer addressed your question, could you mark this as the answer. If not, let me know what else is needed.

Comment: @kcdragon your answer is working fine. But when calculate yesterday date and today date difference, it gives `0 years 1 months 1day`